# Issue Creating Generic Alamofire Service

Tags: swift, xcode, request, alamofire

Hi I'm try to create my own generic servis but I couldn't do that. In my first try in this code I can't get value as T. When I delete cast as T for value Xcode says you should cast it but when I run app it crash because it fails.

```
  @discardableResult
    public func request<T:Codable>(fullUrl url: String,method: HTTPMethod, parameters: Parameters?) -> Promise<T> {
        
        //Add Loading Action
        return Promise<T> { seal in
            sessionManager!.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, headers: headers())
                .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                .responseJSON { response in// Edit, response as your custom model (response: DataResponse<T,AFError>)
                    
                    if response.data != nil {
                        switch response.result {
                        //Add Loading Action
                        case .success(let value):
                            print("ferhan \(value)")
                            seal.fulfill(value as! T)
                        case .failure(let error):
                            guard let data = response.data else {return}
                            guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {return}
                            
                            if let code = response.response?.statusCode {
                                switch code {
                                case 400..<599, 0:
                                    if let code = json["errorCode"] as? Int{
                                        print(code)
                                    }
                                    if let title = json["message"] as? String{
                                        print(title)
                                    }
                                default:
                                    print("Unexpected status")
                                }
                            }
                            //Add Loading Action
                            seal.reject(error)
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("response nil non value \(String(describing: response.error?.localizedDescription))")
                        //Add Loading Action
                        seal.reject(response.error!)
                    }
                }
        }
        
        
    }
```

My second try I get my response as Decodable but Xcode give me error: Value of protocol type 'Decodable' cannot conform to 'Decodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols.

My question is which is a better solution and how to solve than issues.

```
    @discardableResult
    public func requestTwo<T:Codable>(fullUrl url: String,method: HTTPMethod, parameters: Parameters?) -> Promise<T> {
        
        //Add Loading Action
        
        return Promise<T> { seal in
            sessionManager!.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, headers: headers())
                .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                .responseDecodable { (response: DataResponse<T, AFError>) in
                    if response.data != nil {
                        switch response.result {
                        //Add Loading Action
                        case .success(let value):
                            print("ferhan \(value)")
                            seal.fulfill(value)
                        case .failure(let error):
                            guard let data = response.data else {return}
                            guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {return}
                            
                            if let code = response.response?.statusCode {
                                switch code {
                                case 400..<599, 0:
                                    if let code = json["errorCode"] as? Int{
                                        print(code)
                                    }
                                    if let title = json["message"] as? String{
                                        print(title)
                                    }
                                default:
                                    print("Unexpected status")
                                }
                            }
                            //Add Loading Action
                            seal.reject(error)
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("response nil non value \(String(describing: response.error?.localizedDescription))")
                        //Add Loading Action
                        seal.reject(response.error!)
                    }
                }
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: func getData() -> Promise<[TestModel]> {
        service.get(url: "/comments", parameters: ["postId": 1])
    } Also there is lots of more code

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're using the method without specifying the `Codable` type to which the response needs to be converted to. To fix the issue create a `Codable` struct and then declare the expected variable as that particular type so that the compiler can infer which type to decode the data into.

```
struct TestModel: Codable {
    // all the properties...
}

let testObject: Promise<[TestModel]> = requestTwo(fullUrl: <#T##String#>, method: <#T##<<error type>>#>, parameters: <#T##<<error type>>#>)
```

Comment: Just found a solution issue is TestModel was Codable but when I changed to Decodable all issue solved

Comment: Doesn't make sense `Codable = Decodable & Encodable`.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution issue is TestModel was Codable but when I changed to Decodable all issue solved